# ASP.NET MVC Core 1.1.2 Sign-in Form Validation Error

Tags: c#, html, asp.net-mvc, forms, authentication

I have built an e-commerce website using ASP.NET MVC Core 1.1.2. Although I have used the correct methods to implement ASP.NET Authentication, my customers sometimes (70% of the time) get errors in the Sign-in forms. I have looked how they fill in the form and their ModelStates are valid. There is no problem with the information they are providing (or there is, but not related with modelstate). I provide the part of the code where this error occurs. When there is an error, the page redirects to 404 page I have set up in the else statement. Thanks in advance for any help.

Sign-up form  looks like this:
[image: Sign-up form]

AccountController.cs where I redirect to error page if entries are with errors:

```
if (ModelState.IsValid && model.Agreed == "on")
{
    User user = new User { UserName = model.Username, Email = model.Email, RoleSpecific = RoleSpecific.Client };
    IdentityResult result = await _userManager.CreateAsync(user, model.Password);
    if (result.Succeeded)
    {
        await _userManager.AddToRoleAsync(user, "Client");
        Client cli = new Client
        {
            UserID = user.Id,
            HeardOf = model.HeardOf,
            InstagramUsername = model.Instagram,
            TelephoneNumber = model.Telephone,
            TwitterUsername = model.Twitter,
            University = model.University,
            Surname = model.FullName.Split(' ').Last(),
            Name = model.FullName.Substring(0, model.FullName.LastIndexOf(' ')),
            Gender = (Gender)Enum.ToObject(typeof(Gender), Convert.ToInt32(model.Gender))
        };
        await _context.AddAsync(cli);
        _context.SaveChanges();
        var id = _context.Clients.Last().ID;
        var cart = new Cart
        {
            ClientID = id
        };
        await _context.AddAsync(cart);
        _context.SaveChanges();

        string confirmationToken = _userManager.GenerateEmailConfirmationTokenAsync(user).Result;

        string confirmationLink = Url.Action("ConfirmEmail", "Account", new { userid = user.Id, token = confirmationToken }, protocol: HttpContext.Request.Scheme);
        var message = new MimeMessage();
        message.From.Add(new MailboxAddress("unifrogtravel1@yandex.com"));
        message.To.Add(new MailboxAddress(user.Email));
        message.Subject = "Üyelik Onayı";
        message.Body = new TextPart("html")
        {
            Text = "Sayın " + model.FullName + ",<br/> Kaydınızın Tamamlanması için aşağıdaki linke tıklamanız gerekmektedir.<br/><a href=\"" + confirmationLink + "\">Onaylama Linki</a>"
        };
        using (var client = new SmtpClient())
        {
            client.Connect("smtp.yandex.com", 465);
            client.Authenticate("unifrogtravel1@yandex.com", "blapenplefe");
            client.Send(message);
            client.Disconnect(false);
        }


        return RedirectToAction("Index", "Home");
    }
    else
    {
        foreach (var error in result.Errors)
        {
            ModelState.AddModelError(string.Empty, error.Description);
        }
    }
}
return RedirectToAction("Err404", "Home");
}
```

RegisterViewModel.cs:

```
namespace UnifrogBasicDeneme.ViewModels
{
    public class RegisterViewModel
    {
        [Required]
        public string Username { get; set; }

        [Required]
        [EmailAddress]
        public string Email { get; set; }

        [Required]
        [DataType(DataType.Password)]
        public string Password { get; set; }

        [Required]
        [DataType(DataType.Password)]
        [Display(Name = "Confirm Password")]
        [Compare("Password",ErrorMessage ="Yukaridaki sifre ile ayni degil")]
        public string ConfirmPassword { get; set; }

        [Required]
        public string FullName { get; set; }

        public string Gender { get; set; }

        public string Twitter { get; set; }

        public string Instagram { get; set; }

        public string University { get; set; }

        public string HeardOf { get; set; }
        [Required]
        [RegularExpression("^[0-9]+$")]
        public string Telephone { get; set; }

        public string Agreed { get; set; }
    }
```

Sign-up form:

```
<form id="signupForm" method="Post" action="Account/Register">
    <div class="form-group-lg">
        <input type="text" name="UserName" class="form-control bg-ash" id="exampleInputEmail1" placeholder="Kullanıcı Adı">
    </div>
    <div class="form-group-lg">
        <input type="email" name="Email" class="form-control bg-ash" id="exampleInputPassword1" placeholder="Email">
    </div>
    <div class="form-group-lg">
        <input type="password" name="Password" class="form-control bg-ash" id="exampleInputPassword1" placeholder="Şifre">
    </div>
    <div class="form-group-lg">
        <input type="password" name="ConfirmPassword" class="form-control bg-ash" id="exampleInputPassword1" placeholder="Şifre Tekrar">
    </div>

    <br />
    <p>Kullanıcı Bilgileri</p>

    <div class="form-group-lg">
        <input type="text" name="FullName" class="form-control bg-ash" id="exampleInputEmail1" placeholder="Adınız Soyadınız">
    </div>
    <div class="form-group-lg">
        <select class="form-control bg-ash" id="exampleInputEmail1" placeholder="Cinsiyet">
            <option value="1">Kadın</option>
            <option value="0">Erkek</option>
            <option value="2">Diğer</option>
        </select>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group-lg">
        <input type="text" name="Twitter" class="form-control bg-ash" id="exampleInputEmail1" placeholder="Twitter">
    </div>
    <div class="form-group-lg">
        <input type="text" name="Instagram" class="form-control bg-ash" id="exampleInputEmail1" placeholder="Instagram">
    </div>
    <div class="form-group-lg">
        <input type="text" name="University" class="form-control bg-ash" id="exampleInputEmail1" placeholder="Üniversite">
    </div>
    <div class="form-group-lg">
        <input type="text" name="HeardOf" class="form-control bg-ash" id="exampleInputEmail1" placeholder="Kimden Duydunuz">
    </div>
    <div class="form-group-lg">
        <input type="text" name="Telephone" class="form-control bg-ash" id="exampleInputEmail1" placeholder="Cep Telefonunuz">
    </div>
    <div class="checkbox">
        <label>
            <input type="checkbox" name="Agreed"> <a href="~/img/logo/unifrog.png">Unifrog Şartlarını Okudum Kabul Ediyorum</a>
        </label>
    </div>
    <h5>Giriş yapabilmek için emailinize gelen doğrulama linkine tıklamanız gerekmektedir.</h5>
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default">Kaydol</button>
</form>
```

Comment: The most obvious thing is that model.Agreed does not equal on, i.e. they are not clicking the checkbox that presumably agrees terms?  Your error page redirects if they do not do this.  The model does not demand the model.Agreed returns a value so not clicking the tickbox will not cause a modelstate invalidation.  Your form does not include any client side code to force the user to tick the checkbox.  Your controller relies on the checkbox being ticked.  Hence it will redirect to an error page when it is not ticked.

Comment: I know but it's not an issue related with agreeing terms. I've tried many ways but it gives me errors even when I agree the terms.

Comment: Then you need to set a break point in your controller and submit the form locally so you can cycle through the action using F10 to see which line of code is causing a problem.  Also you should have an error summary or the likes on your form page for each error a user could make on the form and then return the form with the errors for the user instead of an error page when the modelstate is not valid.  The errorpage is only generated by 3 issues, either the modelstate is invalid, they haven't selected model.Agreed or the usermanager was unable to create the account 'result.succeeded'.

Answer (score 0):

You should return the view with model and modal errors. So the end of your function  should be like

```
return View("register",model);
```

instead of

```
return RedirectToAction("Err404", "Home");
```

Comment: You are correct he should be returning the view with the model along with the errors to the page, however he currently has nothing in the form to show those errors so this won't help him.  In addition he mentioned the modelstate is valid in his question which means the errors are not from the server side validation, hence even if he did have some code in the form to show the errors there would be none.

Comment: you are right about that. I have noticed those as well but the main problem was  the redirection part. He should correct the  missing validation parts in the form as well. thanks.